# Doctrine + Zend Framework 2: Insert array of data in a many to many relationship

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an application with Zend Framework2 and Doctrine2 as ORM.
I have this Entity called User:

```
namespace Adm\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="user_module",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="module_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $modules;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->modules = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return the $name
 */
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @return the $email
 */
public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @return the $password
 */
public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $id
 */
public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $name
 */
public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $email
 */
public function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $password
 */
public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * Add module
 *
 * @param dm\Entity\Module
 * @return User
 */
public function addModules(Module $modules = null){
    $this->modules[] = $modules;
}

/**
 * Get modules
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getModules(){
    return $this->modules;
}

}
```

See the modules property is a relation Many to Many with a table called user_modules.
And i have the Entity Module as well:

```
namespace Adm\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class Module{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @return the $id
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return the $name
 */
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @return the $status
 */
public function getStatus() {
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $id
 */
public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $name
 */
public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $status
 */
public function setStatus($status) {
    $this->status = $status;
}

}
```

I receive a array variable containing the Post from a form to insert in a table. Each post element have it's property in Entity, as expected. Together, i have a $module variable which is an array containing id's of the modules. My question is: How do i insert this data in the user_module table?
My add function is this:

```
public function addUser($newUser){
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($newUser['name']);
        ...
        $this->getEm()->persist($user);
        $this->getEm()->flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to have `cascade={"persist"}` as mentioned by @skrilled.

Then you need to retrieve the module entities from the database.  You mentioned you have the id's in the $module variable.

You need a DQL statement something like this

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('m')
        ->from('Adm\Entity\Module', 'm')
        ->where('m.id IN (:modules)')
        ->setParameter('modules', $modules);
$moduleEntities= $builder->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

and in your User entity you will need

```
public function addModules(Array $moduleEntities)
{
    foreach ($moduleEntities as $module) {
        if ($module instanceof Module) {
            $this->modules[] = $module;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

finally in your addUser method you will need to add the array of modules from the above DQL

```
public function addUser($newUser, $moduleEntities)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setName($newUser['name']);
    ....
    $user->addModules($moduleEntities);
    $this->getEm()->persist($user);
    $this->getEm()->flush();
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Just amazing @Garry, you are a life saver. It worked perfectly, i just needed to replace: `$moduleEntities= $builder->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);` for `$moduleEntities= $builder->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT);`
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should read about using `cascade`. This will allow you to save/modify/remove the associated relationships and how you expect this to work.

In this case, you would want the relationship to `persist` since you want the associated entities to be saved when user itself is saved.

`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module", cascade={"persist"})`

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

`By default, no operations are cascaded.`

The following cascade options exist:

**persist** : Cascades persist operations to the associated entities.

**remove** : Cascades remove operations to the associated entities.

**merge** : Cascades merge operations to the associated entities.

**detach** : Cascades detach operations to the associated entities.

**refresh** : Cascades refresh operations to the associated entities.

**all** : Cascades persist, remove, merge, refresh and detach operations to associated entities.

Comment: Hi @skrilled, thanks for your answer, i did not know about that. I need to insert the values coming from POST in a table called user_module (which is referenced by the $modules property in User Entity) Can you give me an example of how to do that?